# Google Maps mouseover a continent issue

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How can i handle just the continents in Google Maps?
I mean if the cursor is over Africa, paint the whole of Africa to red, etc.

I haven't seen any method to do this.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Google Map V3 API you can code it manually using overlay polygon and fill it similar to this example [Polygon Fill](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-arrays.html).  To mouseover and paint the whole continent you can use [UI event](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/events.html#UIEvents) and attach a listener and work off that.

As far as getting the "border coordinates," take a look at this [Google Fusion Chart for countries](http://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?dsrcid=423734). You can also export the chart to [KML](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kml_tut.html) and use it to render the continents.